# Is there any way to use elementary os loki as a live usb with persistence?

Tags: usb-drive

I tried all day and several options later I still can't figure it out. Can I even install it on the flash drive?

This is probably a noob question but I appreciate the help. I want a workspace clear of my windows or ubuntu installs, that I can take on the go and focus on work with. Considered Kali but I fell in love with Elementary.

Answer (score 1):

You can install elementary OS from an usb drive to another one, or from cd/dvd to usb.

You must take care making partitions. I recommend you to make two partitions:

- A "root" (/ ) partition to install the OS
- A "home" (/home) partition to persistence.

Avoid a swap partition, in order to preserve usbdrive life.

Choose your usb drive to install Grub.

You can find more information in a post i wrote few months after:

[bitseater's blog](http://bitseater.blogspot.com.es/2016/01/create-bootable-and-persistent-usb.html?m=1)

N.A.: I'm so sorry but my post is in spanish.

Comment: I did that, and it ended up being very slow. Updated the kernel so it would support my hardware, and installed the nvidia graphics driver. 

The screen started flickering.  Still very unresponsive. I think I might wait till Loki is officially released. 

Also, does it make a difference if it's installed on a USB 2.0 drive vs a 3.0? I have both and expected the 3.0 to be faster but I don't know if it's making use of it.

Comment: Run live usb it's better from usb 3.0, according with Ubunti wiki pages: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick